# In a TagLib how can I retrieve the original text code of the body ?

Tags: grails, taglib

Right now when I define a new TagLib, body is some type of Closure

```
class MyTagLib {
   static namespace = "my"

   def tag = { attrs, body ->
           // here I would like to retrieve the actual text of the body not
           // its interpretation
           def text = body() 
   }

   def anothertag = { atts, body ->
       out << body ()
   }
}
```

given the following gsp:

```
<my:tag name="example">
   <h1>This is an example</h1>
   <my:anothertag/>
</my:tag>
```

I want my:tag to retrieve the whole text not just the result of executing h1 and my:anothertab

Thanks

Pascal

Comment: What you mean by "the whole text"? You mean, including the `<my:tag>` definition itself?

Comment: No, just the content of the body which in this case should be:
<h1>This is an example></h1>
<my:anotherTag/>
But right now the body closure when executed will eat <my:anothertag/> and only return <h1>...</h1>

Comment: I don't think you can do that... But what is exactly that you want to accomplish? Maybe there is another way. :)

Comment: I am creating a taglib to easily create and test new widgets with different themes from wrapbootstrap. What I am trying to do is to create a tag that will not only execute the inner body but underneath will prettify the code so that the test application can not only show the widget in action in the current theme but also the code used in its entirely. So for example if my tag was demoCode then it will do 2 things. Let's assume that body could understand a method named content; my tag will be def s = body.content; out << body(); prettify (s);

Comment: I don't think it's possible within Grails itself, because the GSP is compiled to Groovy code. You'll have to find another way to do that -- maybe shipping the templates with the app and reading the files to show the source.

Comment: Doesn't body() simply render the contents into some string/stream? If so couldn't you do what you just mention and assign def s = body() and parse s.

Comment: Also agree with others, the taglib output is event based, just about feeding the servlet output stream via a callback. While you might be able to fetch the parent tag, it wouldn't help much ... The content is already pushed and 'discarded''.

Comment: When body is passed to the taglib it is a GroovyPageTagBody Closure. I think grails should save in that closure the original code so that we could query it like body.originalContent